# sbt - defining custom configuration for sequential tests

Tags: scala, sbt

Some of my tests require that they are sequentially executed. I read about custom configurations on http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html but I am missing something because my configuration is not working properly.

Here it is:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object SchedulingBackendBuild extends Build {
  lazy val SequentialTest = config("sequentialTest") extend(Test)
  def sequentialTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = {
    println("===seq test filter")
    name endsWith "SeqSpec"
  }
  def unitTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = {
    println("===unit test filter")
    !sequentialTestFilter(name)
  }

  lazy val root = Project(id = "scheduling-backend",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings
  ).configs(SequentialTest)
  .settings(inConfig(SequentialTest)(Defaults.testTasks): _*)
  .settings(
      testOptions in Test ++= Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
      testOptions in SequentialTest ++= Seq(Tests.Filter(sequentialTestFilter))
  )
}
```

I want `test` to only execute tests that are not ending with `SeqSpec` and this is working, but when I try to execute `sequentialTest:test` no tests are executed. I added `println` to my filters and I can see that even if I execute `sequentialTest:test` I am getting

```
===unit test filter
===seq test filter
===seq test filter
```

so both filters are executed.

When I type `inspect sequentialTest:testOptions` I am getting

```
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.TestOption]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options for running tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/path/to/project/scheduling-backend/}scheduling-backend/sequentialTest:testOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /path/to/project/scheduling-backend/project/Build.scala:22
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  sequentialTest:testOnly::testOptions
[info]  sequentialTest:testQuick::testOptions
[info]  sequentialTest:test::testOptions
[info] Delegates:
[info]  sequentialTest:testOptions
[info]  test:testOptions
[info]  runtime:testOptions
[info]  compile:testOptions
[info]  *:testOptions
[info]  {.}/sequentialTest:testOptions
[info]  {.}/test:testOptions
[info]  {.}/runtime:testOptions
[info]  {.}/compile:testOptions
[info]  {.}/*:testOptions
[info]  */sequentialTest:testOptions
[info]  */test:testOptions
[info]  */runtime:testOptions
[info]  */compile:testOptions
[info]  */*:testOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  sequentialTest:testOnly::testOptions
[info]  sequentialTest:testQuick::testOptions
[info]  test:testOptions
[info]  test:testQuick::testOptions
[info]  */*:testOptions
[info]  test:testOnly::testOptions
[info]  test:test::testOptions
[info]  sequentialTest:test::testOptions
```

so for me it looks ok, line `22` is `testOptions in SequentialTest ++= Seq(Tests.Filter(sequentialTestFilter))`

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: if I change `++=` operator (appending to the sequence) to `:=` (replacing the sequence) everything works fine (and `:=` operators are used in the documentation). Even so I would want to know why `++=` in this case is bad choice.